# Is the concrete meant to be this patchy after I've sealed it?

Tags: concrete, sealing

I've used 3 coats of Everbuild 403 CONCRETE HARDENER & DUSTPROOFER on my floor and it's come out really patchy. I can't tell whether I've used too much in places or too little in others.

What I can say is that there is now little dust...

Is this the expected result?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How long did you wait between coats?  How long after the coats were these pictures taken?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the tin? Were you within the temperature & humidity recommendations?

Comment: Is that new concrete? What did it look like when you started?

Comment: Nothing a can of concrete floor paint won't improve massively.